# ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256 in hardhat test file

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, chai

Here is a test file.
ethers.getSigners() works fine
ethers.deployContract() works fine
for some reason, ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256 keeps breaking the code with this error:

'
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'solidityKeccak256')

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const crypto = require('crypto');

describe("Pool claim", function () {
  it("Deployment should claim", async function () {
    const [owner, otherAccount] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const PRIVATE_KEY = "******"
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY);


    const Factory = await ethers.deployContract("RewardRegistry");
    const Pool = await Factory.createContracts("++++");

    const ammount = 1;
    const userAddr = await otherAccount.address
    const nonce =  crypto.randomBytes(32)

    const message = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(
        ['address', 'bytes32', 'uint256'],
        [userAddr, nonce, ammount]
      );

    const signature = await wallet.signMessage(message);

    const claimReward = await Pool.claimReward(userAddr, nonce, signature, ammount)

    // expect(await hardhatToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on ethers v6, try this:

```
  const message = ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(
    ['address', 'bytes32', 'uint256'],
    [userAddr, nonce, ammount]
  );
```